# NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher

Tags: java, serialization

Given that `java.util.regex.Matcher` does not implement `Serializable`, is it somehow possible to serialize a class that privately declares and uses

```
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;
```

What, if any, workaround is possible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the **Matcher transient** so that it wont be serialized, as transient variables are not serialized..

```
private transient Matcher matcher;
```

Comment: Remember that `matcher` will be `null` after serialization, no matter what initialization you apply to it.  Any code that uses `matcher` will need to be able to cope with that.  Incidentally, why is that a field?