# Unique instances of string in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

I am very new to Java. I am building an array list to hold partial text from my Git commits. I am running this in a Groovy script within Jenkins.

```
 def commits = sh script: """ git log ${previous_tag}..HEAD --oneline --decorate""", returnStdout: true
 def array = commits.split("\\n");

ArrayList<String> mystats = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
 for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w{7}\\s(MYSTATS-|mystats-)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(array[i]);
  if(matcher.find()) {
     mystats.add(array[i]) 
  }
 }
```

What I want to do then is to create another array to hold unique values (so don't duplicate anything) and have been advised a HashSet is the best approach as it will reject duplicate values

```
// Put all unique mystats matches into a set
 Set<String> mystats_set = new HashSet<String>(mystats.size());
 for(int i =0; i < mystats.size(); i++) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(MYSTATS-|mystats-)\\w+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mystats[i]);
  if(matcher.find()) {
     String id = matcher.group().toUpperCase().toString();
    def jira_json = sh script: '''curl --cert ../certs/dev_cert.p12:password https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk:port_number/rest/api/2/issue/${id}''', returnStdout: true
     mystats_set.add("[" + id + "](https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk/browse/" + id + ")");
  }
 }
```

When this runs I get

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2438)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:132)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:429)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:408)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:356)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field locals
    in field parent
    in field caller
    in field e
    in field program
    in field threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4f76de19

So after some reading it seems that `Set` is not serializable  ? If this is the case how can I just have an ArrayList that holds unique values only and rejects duplicate entries ?

Comment: not sure where the serialization process occurred or where did the app tried to serialize a `Set`, however, you can check the arraylist with `arraylist.contains(str)` before adding it to the arraylist, is that what you need?

Comment: This doesn't look like core java. If you're using groovy or scala (or something else), then please tag that appropriately. And the mentioned exception looks like you're trying the serialize the items of a collection to save them in a file? Which collection is that and why does it contain `Matcher`?

Comment: @tom, apologies, yes using groovy, added tag, im not trying to write to a file, just want to be able to use each item in the set as a variable, like string interpolation in Ruby

Comment: As you can see at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ (I have checked in java 7 version but you can check it in other versions too) HashSet OF COURSE is Serializable. Your problem, following the little piece of log you have added, seems to be with what you are doing with java.util.regex.Matcher (which is the not Serializable one). Perhaps is being used into a Serializable class? (remember, a Serializable class must have all its attributes Serializable also).

Comment: i can't find where the `Matcher` is interacting with the `Set` i doubt this error is related to something else maybe `pattern.matcher(mystats[i])`? can you post the full stacktrace and mark the related line

Comment: I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901766/notserializableexception-java-util-regex-matcher so @facepalmed this confirms what you said, is there a way to re write what i have done then ?

Answer (score 2):

well, after adding the full stacktrace now it appears that `Matcher` is the problem as its not serializable

have you checked [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)?

i quoute:

> you would have noticed a problem:
>
> **java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher** This occurs
>   because the matcher local variable is of a type (Matcher) not
>   considered serializable by Java. Since pipelines must survive Jenkins
>   restarts, the state of the running program is periodically saved to
>   disk so it can be resumed later (saves occur after every step or in
>   the middle of steps such as sh).
>   ...

check the link for more info
the post suggests using annotation `@NonCPS` for the method that `Matcher` is declared in. because i quoute again:

> Such a method will be treated as “native” by the Pipeline engine, and
>   its local variables never saved

ex,

```
@NonCPS
public void doSomeWork(){
    ArrayList<String> mystats = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w{7}\\s(MYSTATS-|mystats-)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(array[i]);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            mystats.add(array[i]) 
        }
    }
}
```

and same for the second part of code where you use a `Matcher`

the other soluotion based on the answer you posted, **using transient** 
you have to declare the `Matcher` out of the method in order to use the `transient` i am not sure about the context of your code or if you can declare `Matcher` and use it in later, ex:

```
transient Matcher matcher = null;

def commits = sh script: """ git log ${previous_tag}..HEAD --oneline --decorate""", returnStdout: true
def array = commits.split("\\n");

ArrayList<String> mystats = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w{7}\\s(MYSTATS-|mystats-)");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(array[i]);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        mystats.add(array[i]) 
    }
}
```

and same for the second part of code, unless they are in the same class (scope) then no need to redeclare `Matcher`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this, it seems like i cannot `transient Matcher matcher = null;` and then use matcher later on in the same scope

Comment: @Richlewis that's strange! i have tried this in Java and it works fine,you can reuse it... any ways what about the annotation ?

Comment: im just trying that now, but need to read up on a few things, firstly not using return in a public void function